# Does HttpRequest emit null values in query string?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call an endpoint in my API using a GET request.

This is the url

```
http://localhost:5050/student?name=%20&school=kingston
```

In my code there is a `HttpRequest req`
when querying it

```
var requestParams = req.QueryString.ToString();
```

I can only see the `school` string without the `name`.

Does `HttpRequest` emit null values by default? If so, is there a way to override that?

I am in need to check for null values for validation and return messages back, if a null value exist in the query string.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC you should be able to declare a Controller and a Method `public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(string name string school)`. The query string parameters will be mapped to those

Comment: Check the docs for QueryString https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8 . It returns null if the query parameter does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryString is of type `NameValueCollection` class and contains
`KEY` and `VALUE` and you must use KEY to access its members.

use

```
var req = HttpContext.Request;
string name = req.QueryString["name"];  
string school = req.QueryString["school"];
```

[NameValueCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=net-5.0)